# How to show 404 error if invalid parameters are selected?

Tags: php, mysql

We have a product catelog page which display product information basis database values

For Instance: If Product is:-
a) soft toys, model is teddy bear (having id as 10) and submodel is between - cushion (300), nappa (301), soft(302)

b) soft toys, model is tiger (having id as 11) and submodel is between - asian (303), african (304)

Then we display information through url - as correct scenario

```
www.xxx.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=product&id=10&sid=300 - Teddy bear cushion

www.xxx.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=product&id=10&sid=301 - Teddy bear nappa

www.xxx.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=product&id=10&sid=302 - Teddy bear soft

www.xxx.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=product&id=11&sid=303 - Tiger Asian

www.xxx.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=product&id=11&sid=304 - Tiger African
```

But - whats also seen that the page is displayed using wrong parameters of different submodel with wrong product

For exacmple

```
www.xxx.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=product&id=10&sid=304 -
```

It shows wrong information as Teddy Bear African

or
`www.xxx.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=product&id=11&sid=300` - 
It shows wrong information as Tiger Cushion

wherein in actual its wrong as such product page never exists (due to incorrect sid matching with product id) - but due to url are shown

How to put in 404 error through database if id and sid does not match ?

Comment: may be cache problem .try to clear your browser history

Comment: not a cache issue, anyhow do you have a way to display 404 if both id & sid are not matching

Comment: just use if condition to show if(database id ==id) { echo "whole page content" }else{ echo "incorrect id ";  or redirect to 404 page using header('Location:file404.php');  }

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$validOptions = getCategoryProducts($id);

if (!in_array($sid, $validOptions){
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    echo "<h1>Product Not Found</h1>";
    echo "The product that you have requested could not be found.";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: i am on mysql 5.6, joomla, php 5.6 - unsure on above, as it doesnt work